# Using a FileWatcher in a Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a client that invokes a [web method].  In the [web method] I am checking for the existence of certain files which is in itself contained in a while(true) loop. When there are files present or a time-out occurs the callback is returned to the client.

I have noticed running it his was the wp3 process climbs in memory usage.

Someone told me that if use a FileWatcher instead of a while(true) loop that the memory is placed on the .Net framework instead of the IIS process. I was trying to test this but I could not see how to return the callback to the client when a file is 'found'.

My code:

**[Desktop App]**

```
private void _tmrRequestHandler_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
_tmrRequestHandler.enabled = false;
//call my web service async
}
catch
{
_tmrRequestHandler.enabled = true;
}
}

private void WSconnector_GetRequestsCompleted(object sender, wsConnector.GetRequestsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//do stuff
_tmrRequestHandler.enabled = true;
}
```

**[web server]**   - the old way

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetRequests(string _mac)
{
   string[] _response = null;
   while (_fileCount == 0)
   {
    string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles("my root path" + _mac, "*.dat");
    _fileCount = _files.Length;
    if (_files.Length > 0)
    {
     _response = new string[_files.Length];
     _files.CopyTo(_response, 0);
     return _response;
    }
 }
```

}

**[web server]**   - the proposed new way

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetRequests(string _mac)
{
    string[] _response = null;
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = AbsoluteRequestQueue + _mac;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "*.dat*";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //file found!!
    //HOW DO I GIVE CALLBACK TO MY CLIENT AND SHOULD I REALLY BE CONSIDEREING DOING IT THIS WAY??
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Had to delete my answer as I misread your question - to be honest I'm not sure how a file system watcher would help you here if you're just scanning a folder to return a list of files in the folder. FSW are used to keep an eye on a folder and notify when specific events happen.

Comment: Hi, no worries.  I was just making sure I had not missed anything.  I am trying to introduce real time messaging.  By placing the emphasis on the [web method] I was trying to emulate a 'push' service and reduce the number of calls from Client to Server.  SignalR does not work for me as it results to long-polling on pre-Windows 8 OS.

Comment: why in a `while(true)` loop? Do you need time-critical notification of changes? A check every second would get the job done without checking a few million times per second.

Comment: @WimOmbelets Hi, thanks for replying.  It takes 'x' amount of time to invoke the [web method].  I cannot see how it could call it a few million times per second?  I would be lucky to get 1 call a second (with a reply after checking for files) don't you think?  And yes, it is a real-time application (or near as)..

Comment: What about [Duplex WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)?